# How to clone a git repository that's stored on a server?

Tags: git

I want to be able to make changes to a project, the project is hosted on a server in a git repository. I want to add a collaborator to the project so I must clone the repository and of course, use the add origin command to create the link between the version on my PC and the one hosted on the Server. What are the steps I have to take to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: You do not need to run `git init` or `git remote add origin` if you clone - clone does both of those and then pulls.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The source you shared is probably not the best up-to-date guide, since it is locked and it says at the very top that the question "[...] is off-topic but has historical significance." There are plenty of other relevant online guides that continue to be updated that can be found easily, like [W3Schools's guide](https://www.w3schools.com/git/).

Answer (score 2):

Use `git clone <location_on_server>`.